# Selecting a Max and Min from the same column in SQL in a single query

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains entries for each step in the supplier delivery process.

For example: arrived, on-premise, offloaded, and off-premise.

When each of these steps happens, we capture the timestamp it happened on.

I want to select the duration it was on-premise for all the suppliers that have a status ID bigger or equal to 30. in other words, the biggest status ID - the smallest status ID Where the smallest Status ID >= 30

Note that not all the steps are necessarily completed, I need to select the highest step for that supplier.

How do I do this in SQL?

My supplier delivery history table's columns:

```
GUID ID,
DATETIME TimeStamp, 
GUID FK_SupplierDeliveryID, 
TINYINT FK_SupplierDeliveryStatusID
```

Supplier delivery status table's columns:

```
TINYINT ID,
NVARCHAR Description,
```

Supplier table:

```
GUID ID, 
NVARCHAR SupplierName
```

Ideally, I would like to return the following fields from the query:

```
SupplierID, SupplierName, LastStatus, Time In, Time Out, Elapse
```

where `Supplier ID` is the ID of the supplier table, `Supplier Name` is the description of the supplier table, `LastStatus` is the biggest `StatusKey` captured for the supplier, `Time In` is the date of the entry where the `StatusKey = 30`, `Time Out` is the date of the entry of the biggest `StatusKey` captured for the supplier is `= 40` else null, and `Elapse = Time Out - Time In`

[image]

[image]

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID,
    MAX(sdh.StatusKey) AS HighestStatus,
    MIN(sdh.StatusKey) AS LowestStatus,
    MAX(sdh.StatusDate) AS HighestDate,
    MIN(sdh.StatusDate) AS LowestDate
FROM
    SupplierDeliveryStatusHistory AS sdh
WHERE
    sdh.StatusKey> 30
GROUP BY 
    sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID,
    sdh.StatusKey
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Please tag yor database.

Comment: The min in the context is the entry where the Status key = 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're aggregating on the `sdh.StatusKey` column, so you shouldn't group by it:

```
SELECT
      sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID,
      MAX(sdh.StatusKey) AS HighestStatus,
      MIN(sdh.StatusKey) AS LowestStatus
FROM
      SupplierDeliveryStatusHistory AS sdh
WHERE
      sdh.StatusKey> 30
GROUP BY 
      sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID -- sdh.StatusKey removed here
```

Comment: I expanded on this and it worked, thank you 

`SELECT
      sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID,
      MAX(sdh.StatusKey) AS HighestStatus,
      MIN(sdh.StatusKey) AS LowestStatus,
      MAX(sdh.StatusDate) AS HighestDate,
     MIN(sdh.StatusDate) AS LowestDate
FROM
      SupplierDeliveryStatusHistory AS sdh
WHERE
      sdh.StatusKey>= 30
GROUP BY 
      sdh.FK_SupplierDeliveryID-- sdh.StatusKey removed here,
`